# Generating a dynamic Localhost URL path in HTML href

Tags: html, asp.net, model-view-controller, localhost

I am working on an ASP.net web app and have some redirect links on a page.

The page takes the controller name, and an ID, and the URL when clicked would be like https://localhost:1234/Page/1

Atm, I have hardcoded the href redirect to be like "https://localhost:1234/Page/1"

and another href redirect to be like "https://localhost:1234/page/2"

The question I have, if someone else runs the program their localhost server may be different, what is the best solution to this? So that the Localhost part is dynamic, and I only feed in the controller and ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `~/` will redirect to the home page. So in your example you can use `~/page/{pageNumber}`